# Left Navigation pointing to Old Farm

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have backed up and restored the site collections from PROD to TEST farm Using DB attach process. Backup restore has successfully completed, but left navigation in Test environment is redirecting to Prod "URL" in all site collections.

Do we have any scripts or do we need to change in webpage in QuickLaunch, or do I need to change all 107 Site collections manually going 'Site Action'

Please help me out if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change those items programmatically, since it seems those menu items where customised.

Waldek in his blog created a script that allows something similar you will be able to modify it to suit your needs:

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-configuring-menu-items-sharepoint-2010/

here is the script for future reference:

```
function Set-Navigation {
    param (
        $WebUrl,
        $MenuItems
    )

    $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($WebUrl)
    $web = $site.OpenWeb()

    # fake context
    [System.Web.HttpRequest] $request = New-Object System.Web.HttpRequest("", $web.Url, "")
    $sw = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
    $hr = New-Object System.Web.HttpResponse($sw)
    [System.Web.HttpContext]::Current = New-Object System.Web.HttpContext($request, $hr)
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl]::SetContextWeb([System.Web.HttpContext]::Current, $web)

    # initalize what has to be initialized
    $pweb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
    $dictionary = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]]"
    $collection = $pweb.Navigation.GlobalNavigationNodes

    # get current nodes
    $globalNavSettings = New-Object System.Configuration.ProviderSettings("GlobalNavSiteMapProvider", "Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")
    $globalNavSettings.Parameters["NavigationType"] = "Global"
    $globalNavSettings.Parameters["EncodeOutput"] = "true"
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider] $globalNavSiteMapProvider = [System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper]::InstantiateProvider($globalNavSettings, [type]"Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider")
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapNode] $currentNode = $globalNavSiteMapProvider.CurrentNode
    $children = $currentNode.GetNavigationChildren([Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.NodeTypes]::Default, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.NodeTypes]::Default, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.OrderingMethod]::Manual, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.AutomaticSortingMethod]::Title, $true, -1);

    # reorder nodes
    [Array]::Reverse($menuItems)
    $menuNodes = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapNode]
    foreach ($node in $children) {
        $menuNodes.Add($node)
    }

    foreach ($menuItem in $menuItems) {
        $node = $null
        foreach ($p in $menuNodes) {
            if ($p.InternalUrl -eq $menuItem) {
                $node = $p
                break
            }
        }

        if ($node -ne $null) {
            [void] $menuNodes.Remove($node)
            [Void] $menuNodes.Insert(0, $node)
        }
    }

    foreach ($node in $menuNodes) {
        Write-Host "$($node.InternalUrl)..." -NoNewline
        $quickId = Get-QuickId $node
        if ($quickId -ne $null) {
            [string]$typeId = $null;
            if (($node.Type -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.NodeTypes]::Area) -or ($node.Type -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.NodeTypes]::Page)) {
                if ($node.PortalProvider.NavigationType -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalNavigationType]::Current) {
                    $typeId = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalNavigationType]::Current.ToString() + "_" + $node.Type.ToString()
                }
                else {
                    $typeId = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalNavigationType]::Global.ToString() + "_" + $node.Type.ToString()
                }
            }
            else {
                $typeId = $node.Type.ToString();
            }

            $id = $quickId.Split(',');
            $objId = New-Object Guid($id[0]);
            $nodeId = [System.Int32]::Parse($id[1]);

            $navigationNode = Get-NavigationNode $objId $nodeId $node.InternalTitle $node.InternalUrl $node.Description $node.Type $node.Target $node.Audience $collection $dictionary
            $containsNode = $false
            foreach ($mi in $menuItems) {
                if ($mi -eq $node.InternalUrl) {
                    $containsNode = $true
                    break
                }
            }

            if ($containsNode) {
                $pweb.Navigation.IncludeInNavigation($true, $objId)
            }
            else {
                $pweb.Navigation.ExcludeFromNavigation($true, $objId)
            }
        }
        Write-Host "DONE"
    }

    $pweb.Web.Update()

    [System.Web.HttpContext]::Current = $null
}

function Get-QuickId {
    param (
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapNode] $node
    )

    $quickId = $null

    $portalSiteMapNodeType = $node.GetType()
    $QuickId = $portalSiteMapNodeType.GetProperty("QuickId", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags] "Instance, NonPublic")
    $quickId = [string] $QuickId.GetValue($node, $null)

    $quickId
}

function Get-NavigationNode {
    param (
        [Guid] $objId,
        [int] $nodeId,
        [string] $name,
        [string] $url,
        [string] $description,
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.NodeTypes] $nodeType,
        [string] $target,
        [string] $audience,
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNodeCollection] $collection,
        $oldDictionary
    )

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode] $node = $null
    if (($objId -ne [Guid]::Empty) -and ($nodeId -ge 0)) {
        if ($oldDictionary.TryGetValue($nodeId, [ref]$node)) {
            $oldDictionary.Remove($nodeId)
            $node = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.SPNavigationSiteMapNode]::UpdateSPNavigationNode($node.Navigation.GetNodeById($node.Id), $null, $name, $url, $description, $target, $audience, $false)
            $node.MoveToLast($collection)
        }

        return $node
    }

    $node = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.SPNavigationSiteMapNode]::CreateSPNavigationNode($name, $url, $nodeType, $collection)
    return [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.SPNavigationSiteMapNode]::UpdateSPNavigationNode($node, $null, $name, $node.Url, $description, $target, $audience, $false)
}

Write-Host "Configuring Navigation..."
$menuItems = "/site5", "/site4", "/site3", "/site2", "/site1"
Set-Navigation "http://publishing" $menuItems
Write-Host "Navigation Configuration completed"
```